# Opening JSF page is very slow and eventually ends up in 404

Tags: eclipse, jsf, glassfish

I'm building a Java EE project with GlassFish as the server. It's very slow when I try to open de project on Chrome. Sometimes it doesn't even open, it loads for a long time and then shows error 404. This is the adress: `http://localhost:8080/TpJava3/index.xhtml`. In Eclipse it's fine if I run the Facelets page everytime. However, if I just paste the URL in the Eclipse browser, it's the same thing. Also I tried to run `http://localhost:4848/TpJava3/test.xhtml`. It opened for 3 seconds, then went to an error 404 page.

`web.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>TpJava3</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/icefaces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.icefaces.coalesceResources</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.icefaces.strictSessionTimeout</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.icefaces.ace.gmapKey</param-name>
    <param-value>AIzaSyAATyWVqT2qNusNGmcVTyQ0QmymkpU-B5o</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.gmapKey</param-name>
    <param-value>AIzaSyAcAbAa7AL1DLU0785OeWn2byf4XOsm7KM</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.icesoft.faces.webapp.CompatResourceServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/xmlhttp/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>png</extension>
    <mime-type>image/png</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Have you tried to re-deploy?  Stop and start the domain again? Anything beyond these general suggestions will require you to provide more relevant information.

Comment: I have cleaned and restarted my glassfish server but it's still not working. I'm sorry, I'm not too sure what information to provide :/.

Comment: Versions of all components. Exact `JavaEE` technology used. Possibly some code.

Comment: Ok, Glassfish 4.0, JSF 3.2, myibatis 3.2 and JDK7, tell me if you need more info. My Glassfish is set to automaticly publish when ressources changes.

Comment: I guess the next step would be to post your `web.xml`.

Comment: Ok thank you, I am posting my web.xml right now.

Comment: @user2511414 that's a typo, it should be JSF 2.2 that's already shipped in GlassFish 4 **or** OP comes from the future

Comment: With the provided information, it is still hard enough to determine the problem in your environment. I can only come up with you deploying the artifacts (war, jar, ear, etc) in the Eclipse folder and not in GlassFish deploy folder. You can verify this by going to the server view, double-clicking the GlassFish server instance you've configured, a window will appear with some settings of your server, go to *Server Locations* and make sure the artifacts will be deployed on GF installation instead of workspace metadata.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza  - Since OP in his comments indicated that he has set GlassFish to **auto-publish**, could there still be a problem with a wrong folder?

Comment: @PM77-1 no, that should not be a problem. When I work with Java EE projects, I disable any automatic project build and deployments and set the deploy folder inside the web application server folder (tomcat, jboss, gf or whichever it is), I prefer to do all this manually and save any headache like the war was cached or something and couldn't be removed.

Answer (score 0):

there is no relation between your web browser and Java EE Application. I deploy all my Java EE Application on chrome, Firefox without difference. Also 4848 is the port of Admin page so
the question here what are  you really deploying did you deploy the Ear file which contain EJB,War or deploy the war that has EJB project as Dependeny

note:

always specify only one welcome page in your web.xml. not many pages as you are doing

Comment: Can you please provide a reference that shows that having multiple welcome pages leads to a problem?  Otherwise this is **not** an answer but simply a comment.